# Updating isoparser-1.0-RC-37 from isoparser-1.0-RC-15 issues in getDecodingTimeEntries()

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mp4parser

I found sample code to cut the video based on the duration from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034225/facing-issue-with-mp4parser),
but i cannot find method getDecodingTimeEntries() in  isoparser-1.0-RC-37. It's available in the older version of isoparser(-1.0-RC-15).

So my question are.

- Why that methode removed from the update jar?
- Is there any alternate method available?
- Any one have example source to trim(Cut by duration) using
  isoparser-1.0-RC-37 jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After  search of 2 to 3 days i found the example for the updated library. 
https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser